# Spivak: Find a function $g$ such that $\int_0^{x^2} tg(t)dt=x+x^2$. What happens at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, proof-explanation

The following is a problem from Ch. 14, "The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus", from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 5. Find a function $g$ such that
>
> (ii) $\int_0^{x^2} tg(t)dt=x+x^2$
>
> (Notice that $g$ is not assumed continuous at $0$.)

Here is my solution, which is broadly the same as the solution manual solution, but I am hung up on certain details.

Let $$f(x)=\int_0^{x^2} tg(t)dt$$ $$h(x)=xg(x)$$ $$f_1(x)=\int_0^x h$$ $$f_2(x)=x^2$$

Then $f=f_1 \circ f_2$ and $f'(x)=f_1'(f_2(x))f_2'(x)$.

Given some $x$, if $h$ is continuous at $x$ then we can apply the first fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC1) to obtain

$$f'(x)=x^2g(x^2)\cdot 2x=2x^3g(x^2)$$

Since $f(x)=x+x^2$ then we have

$$f'(x)=2x^3g(x^2)=1+2x$$

$$g(x^2)=\frac{1}{2x^3}+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}$$

Note that $g$ is not defined at $0$, so there no way to write $xg(x)$ for $x=0$. We can however, defined $g$ as

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2x\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{x}, \text{ if } x\neq 0 \\ 0, \text{ if } x=0  \end{cases}$$

Then

$$h(x)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}+1, \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 0, \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

I believe $h$ looks something like

[image]

Is $h$ integrable? It is not bounded near $0$. In Spivak the definition of integrability is

> A function $f$ which is bounded on $[a,b]$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ if
> $\sup\{L(f,P)\}=\inf\{U(f,P)\}=\int_a^b f$.

Note that if $l(x)=\sqrt{x}+x$ then $l'(x)=h(x)$. Thus, since $h$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ we can apply FTC2 and have

$$\int\limits_{x_0}^{x^2} h= l(x^2)-l(x_0)=x+x^2-\sqrt{x_0}-x_0$$

The issue is, what justifies allowing $x_0$ to be $0$, as the solution manual allows?

Comment: Could you try differentiating the given equation?

Comment: $1/\sqrt{x}$ is integrable near $0$. In general, $x^{-p}$ is integrable near $0$ whenever $p < 1$.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3624037/finding-a-function-g-satisfying-int-0x2-operatornametgtdt-xx2?rq=1) question is very similar, as is [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965726/find-a-function-g-such-that-int-0x2tgtdt-x-x2?rq=1).

Comment: A good question would be: Can we find a  $\,\, g$ defined also for negative $x$ ?? I guess the answer is no!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right: Spivak is inconsistent here. It's only later, near the end of the exercises from that chapter, that he defines a “kind of ‘improper integral’ in which the interval is bounded, but the *function* is not”.